# unicode string manipulation in c

Tags: c, string, unicode, utf-8

I am using gcc in linux mint 15 and my terminal understands unicode. I will be dealing with UTF-8. I am trying to obtain the base word of a more complex unicode string. Sort of like trimming down the word 'alternative' to 'alternat' but in a different language. Hence I will be required to test the ending of each word.

In c and ASCII, I can do something like this

```
if(string[last_char]=='e')
    last_char-=1; //Throws away the last character
```

Can I do something similar with unicode? That is, something like this :

```
if(string[last_char]=='ഒ')
    last_char=-1
```

Comment: You should look at wstring and u32string (better if you are targetting c++11).

Comment: my bad, best is to use c++ for that anyway ;)

Comment: Easiest solution I've found is to convert the UTF-8 string to UTF32, then each element in the UTF32-string is exactly one Unicode character, though there are still some pitfalls with this approach. It might help if you specify what you want to compare to.

Comment: Also, this article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html is really good at explaining the basics and doing away with some widespread misconceptions about Unicode.

Comment: I will be comparing 2 unicode letters (or strings) in the same language.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
Sorry as @chux said I just notified you are asking in C. Anyway the same principle holds.

In C you can use `wscanf` and `wprintf` to do I/O with wide char strings. If your characters are inside BMP you'll be fine. Just replace `char *` with `wchar_t *` and do all kinds of things as usual.

For serious development I'd recommend convert all strings to `char32_t` for processing. Or use a library like `ICU`.

If what you need is just remove some given characters in the string, then maybe you don't need the complex unicode character handling. Treat your unicode characters as a raw `char *` string and do whatever string operations over it.

The old C++ oriented answer is reproduced below, for reference.

---

#### The easy way

Use [std::wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

It's basically an `std::string` but individual characters are typed `wchar_t`.

And for IO you should use `std::wcin` and `std::wcout`. For example:

```
std::wstring str;
std::wcin >> str;
std::wcout << str << std::endl;
```

However, in some platforms `wchar_t` is 2-byte wide, which means characters outside [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) will not work. This should be okay for you I think, but should not be used in serious development. For more text on this topic, read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful).

#### The hard way

Use a better unicode-aware string processing library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

#### The C++11 way

Use some mechanisms to convert your input string to `std::u32string` and you're done. The conversion routines can be hand-crafted or using an existing library like ICU.

As `std::u32string` is formed using `char32_t`, you can safely assume you're dealing with Unicode correctly.